# Angular best practice to avoid '' in formGroup

Tags: angular, angular-forms

In my Angular application I have some input attached to FormControl.
When I delete a normal input field if I check the value in the associated FormControl I have a `''`.

This is a problem because the server wants a `null` value instead of `''` so at the moment I have a method in the service that rebuilds my object putting `null` value in the `''` place.

So is there a way to do it in a better mode? What is the best practice in this case?

Answer (score 1):

A simple way would be to subscribe to the form control's value changes, react on cases when the value is an empty string, and then set the value to `null`. A simplified example:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  template: `
    <input type="text" [formControl]="formControl"><br/>
    Current value: {{ formControl.value |json }}
  `
})
export class FormComponent {

  formControl = new FormControl();

  constructor() {
    this.formControl.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      if (value === '') {
        this.formControl.patchValue(null);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Of course, it depends on your use case if this is actually doable. If you have a lot of form controls that you cannot centrally control, you might need to come up with another solution.

Something slightly more complex, but feasible, is to add a HTTP interceptor that replaces empty strings with `null` in your request bodies going out to your server.

Comment: Thanks, yes it is a good way.
In my case, I usually have FormGroup and FormArray, is there a way to do it?

Comment: NOT it's a bad idea. You force Angular to realize the check each change

Comment: @Eliseo I don't see that happening. It adds one more change detection cycle simply (the one time that `patchValue(null)` is emitted, and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

My aproach is another. You general send the data to a service, so is in the service where you check the values. e.g.

```
saveData(data:any)
{
    data.name=data.name ||null
    data.address.address2=data.address.address2 || null
    ....
    data.myarrayOfFormGroup.forEach(x=>{
       x.value=x.value|| null
    })
    data.myArrayOfFormControls=data.myarrayOfFormControl.map(x=>x||null)
    this.httpClient.pos("...",data)
}
```